# Elastic Beanstalk & Docker: problem with elastic beanstalk spawning multiple docker containers

Tags: docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, supervisord

I'm forced to use elastic beanstalk (eb) and Docker in deploying. When I build & run my container locally it boots up and runs well. I'm using supervisord to boot some ruby code (clockwork and Rails/puma)

When deploying using eb, I see how eb spawns several consecutive containers until all just chokes down:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
232bbe498977        a4a6fd70537b        "supervisord -c /etc…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   80/tcp              silly_williams
a9e21774575e        a4a6fd70537b        "supervisord -c /etc…"   2 minutes ago        Up 2 minutes        80/tcp              trusting_murdock
945f51ef510f        a4a6fd70537b        "supervisord -c /etc…"   3 minutes ago        Up 3 minutes        80/tcp              blissful_stonebraker
6e51470ddce8        a4a6fd70537b        "supervisord -c /etc…"   4 minutes ago        Up 4 minutes        80/tcp              lucid_ramanujan
2689568ceb6d        a4a6fd70537b        "supervisord -c /etc…"   4 minutes ago        Up 4 minutes        80/tcp              keen_mestorf
```

Where should I be looking for the root to this behavior? Can the container be creating this behaviour or is eb configured in a wrong way? 
(I apologize that I'm a bit too unspecific with details since I'm not in full control of the environment)

Answer (score 1):

I eventually realized I had been tampering with some settings, and had set monitoring to basic. Once put to Enhanced it only booted one container and things started to work again!

In:
Elastic Beanstalk > [my application] > Configuration > monitoring > System: Enhanced.